# Add Class to Array of ID's in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using .map to get an array of element IDs (this is named 'ids') that have a 'default-highlight' class. After removing that class on mouseenter, I want to return that class to those specific id's (basically, leave it how I found it).

Two things are causing me trouble right now:

1. When I dynamically add data-ids to the td elements and then use those data-ids to create the array of 'ids' my mouseenter stops adding the 'HIGHLIGHT' class (NO idea why this is happening)
2. On mouseleave I can't loop through the 'ids' and return the 'default-highlight' class to the elements they originally were on

I figure I should be using something like this, but it obviously isn't working:

```
$.each(ids, function() {
   $(this).addClass('default-highlight');
});
```

I have tried a number of things, but keep coming up short. I am attaching a link to a [codepen.io where I use data-ids](http://codepen.io/nabosh/pen/RWRjWQ) that are being dynamically added to the table (this one the mouseenter doesn't work) and a [codepen one](http://codepen.io/nabosh/pen/JYKMZw?editors=101) where I am using regular IDs for the default highlight and everything appears to work like it is supposed to be (It isn't, since I want to be using the dynamically generated data-ids and then the subsequently produced array to reapply those classes).

Both of these codepens have a gif at top showing how the interaction should work.

If anything is unclear, please let me know. Thanks for reading!

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: ids.get is not a function`. Replace `$('#output').text(ids.get().join(', '));` with `$('#output').text(ids.join(', '));` [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVyopd)

Comment: Thanks @ᴀʀᴛᴜʀғɪʟɪᴘɪᴀᴋ for pointing that out - fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like storing the IDs and using those is overkill when you can store a reference to the jQuery element directly:

```
$highlightCells = $('.default-highlight').removeClass('default-highlight')
```

And later give the class back:

```
$highlightCells.addClass('default-highlight')
```

Here's a codepen fork: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbOvZR?editors=101

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `#` before id selector

```
$.each(ids, function() {
   $('#'+this).addClass('default-highlight');
});
```

or you can use common selector by the help of `map()` and `join()`

```
$(ids.map(function(i, v) {
  return '#' + v;
}).join()).addClass('default-highlight');
```

or you can add `#` when getting the id's and then you just need to join them

```
var ids = $('.default-highlight').map(function(i) {
  return '#'+$(this).data('id');
}).get();
...
...
...
$(ids.join()).addClass('default-highlight');
```

Comment: Thanks, giving this a shot

Comment: @NealJones : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$.each(ids, function() {
   $("#" + this).addClass('default-highlight');
});
```

Comment: `this` in string array isn't what you want it to be

Comment: This will be the same as mapping all the array elements with the `#` and adding the class right?

Comment: not sure why...but `$.each` doesn't assign the array element to `this` when it is a string, only object